# How to get all comments and likes for a facebook post?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-like, facebook-comments

If you have the `read_stream` permission and you get the posts of a facebook user, for each post you only get the top X comments and top X likes. Is there a way to paginate through the likes/comments and get them all?

If there's any FQL query which would return ALL likes or comments for a post, or let me page through them 20 or so at a time, that would work too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edited:

You have to get each status to get all comments/likes on that status. If you have a specific post that you want the comments for:

```
$post     = '100003978045030_105596009583000';
$comments = array();
$done     = false;
$options  = array();
$path     = '/' . $post . '/comments';

while(!$done){
    try{
        $data = $facebook->api($path, 'GET', $options);
    } catch(FacebookApiException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
        $data = null;
        $done = true;
    }
    if(!is_null($data)){
        $comments = array_merge($comments, $data['data']);
        if(isset($data['paging']['next']) && !empty($data['paging']['next'])){
            $parts = parse_url($data['paging']['next']);
            $path  = $parts['path'];
            parse_str($parts['query'], $options);
        } else {
            $done = true;
        }
    }
}

print_r($comments);
```

Comment: if you could test it to make sure the paging link is provided for more than X comments i'll accept :).

Answer (score 1):

In FQL, you just have to query the [comment](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/comment/) or [like](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/like/) table:

```
SELECT post_id, text, fromid FROM comment 
   WHERE post_id IN 
      (SELECT post_id FROM stream WHERE source_id = USER_OR_PAGE_ID
       AND comments.count > 0 )
   LIMIT 0, 100
```

This will give you the first 100 results (but less than 100 may be returned, since those not visible to you will be filtered out).

Note that the like table is hobbled for page streams.

Comment: Yes. If you're looking at a page stream, Facebook has made it almost impossible to find people who like the page that you are not personally friends with.

Comment: Unfortunately, FQL is not available anymore. Nice job Facebook. NOT.